# How do I get the size of the largest connected component of a graph in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm building a graph from an RDD of tuples of source and destination nodes, like this:

```
Graph.fromEdgeTuples(rawEdges = edgeList, 1)
```

1. First off, I did not quite understand what the second parameter is. From the documentation,

   > defaultValue the vertex attributes with which to create vertices
   >   referenced by the edges

   I still don't get it.
2. Second, I cannot find anything to compute the size of the biggest component. There is no `foreach` implemented, nor `map` or `reduceByKey`, or anything else after invoking the `connectedComponents` method.

Answer (score 3):

1. `defaultValue` is an attribute assigned to all created edges:

   ```
   val graph = Graph.fromEdgeTuples(sc.parallelize(Seq(
     (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5))), 1)

   graph.edges.map(_.attr).distinct.collect 
   // Array[Int] = Array(1)
   ```
2. Extract component ids and do a worcount:

   ```
   val ids = graph.connectedComponents.vertices map((v: (Long, Long)) => v._2)
   ids.map((_, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
   ```